# Open Graph pages: can I use a stub/forwarding page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have a page containing a list of activities. I want multiple FB Like buttons: for the page itself and for each of the individual activities.

In order for the page itself to be Liked, it needs [OpenGraph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) tags. But if the page has the tags, then the Like button, according to the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), will ignore the `url` parameter of the Like buttons. From the docs:

> > When you use Open Graph tags, the Like button posts a link to the og:url instead of the URL in the Like button code.

**Possible solution** So, my idea is to create small stub pages that will only contain the Open Graph tags and a meta redirect tag to the real activity page.

Has anyone tried this? Or some other solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is feasible, I have tried it before: creating separate pages that only contain OG meta tags. However, the problem with this is, once a user likes the item, it posts automatically on the user's wall saying "*Larry likes a link*". When his friends see this, and click on the attached link, they will see a white screen (your og:meta-only pages). but since you said you will have redirect then this is good.

On the side, you had a wrong interpretation about this quote:

> When you use Open Graph tags, the Like
>   button posts a link to the og:url
>   instead of the URL in the Like button
>   code.

It doesn't mean "*When you use Open Graph tags **on the root page***". It means when you use Open Graph tags on the pages you were linking to in the like buttons.

Also, what it meant by "posts a link" is posting a link on the user's wall. Liking open graph pages automatically posts to wall now. It didn't say "using the link" on og:url of the current page.